# How do i add pause button for automatic slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I got the jquery from w3schools, i have looked and tried to add a working pause button but it doesnt work.

```
<div class="realisatie" id="slideshow"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto1.png" alt="Begin van een werk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto2.png" alt="Verdere progressie"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto3.png" alt="Nog niet gevoegd eindwerk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto4.png" alt="Eindwerk + gevoegd"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto5.png" alt="Begin van een tweede werk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto6.png" alt="Progressie van tweede werl"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto7.png" alt="Nog niet gevoegd eindwerk 2"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto8.png" alt="Eindwerk van een tweede werk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto9.jpg" alt="Begin van een derde werk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto10.jpg" alt="Progressie van eend erde werk"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto11.jpg" alt="Derde eindwerk nog niet gevoegd"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto12.jpg" alt="Derde eindwerk + gevoegd"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto13.jpg" alt="Houten vloer gelegd"> 
        <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto14.png" alt="Andere houten vloer gelegd"> 
    </div>
<button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
```

This is my scrip from w3 schools:

```
<script>
        var myIndex = 0;
        carousel();

        function carousel() {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Realisaties");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            myIndex++;
            if (myIndex > x.length) {
                myIndex = 1
            }
            x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
        }
    </script>
```

This is the code i tried from https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/zqVGQK/

```
var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

function pauseSlideshow(){
    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
    playing = false;
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
}

function playSlideshow(){
    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    playing = true;
    slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function(){
    if(playing){ pauseSlideshow(); }
    else{ playSlideshow(); }
};
```

Comment: Where is what you tried? I don't see any code that you wrote yourself.

Comment: I tried https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/zqVGQK/ this but changed the names etc. A friend tried it with a code he wrote himself but i didnt save that code

Comment: Update your question with the code you tried

Comment: When i use that code: The button changes from pause to play but it doesnt pause the slideshow

Comment: Where is the button in your HTML? I don't see it.

Comment: I updated the question for it

Comment: Pausing the codepen works for me in Chrome.

Comment: The last line in each of your play and pause functions don't do anything. In your pause function, the function clearInterval() uses a parameter slideInterval which isn't set. Similarly, in your play function, nextSlide isn't set anywhere and slideInterval is set but never used. It looks like you're trying to set variables in one function and call them in another. This doesn't work. The scope of your variables is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues in your code that @Brad has mentioned them in his comment. So I will fix those and change one or two lines for you:

1. remove the `carousel();` at the top of your script. We will call `playSlideshow()` instead at the end of the code.
2. Remove `setTimeout(carousel, 2000);` at the end of the `carousel()` function. We will set the interval in the `playSlideshow()` function later.
3. in the `playSlideshow()` function at this line `slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);` you have to change **nextSlide** to **carousel**, So `carousel()` function will be called every 2 seconds.
4. and at last we will call `carousel();` one time(to avoid first 2 seconds delay) and then `playSlideshow();`

That's all. Your `html` part looks fine. So I did not change it.

To sum thing up, your code will look like this:

**html**

```
<div class="realisatie" id="slideshow"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto1.png" alt="Begin van een werk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto2.png" alt="Verdere progressie"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto3.png" alt="Nog niet gevoegd eindwerk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto4.png" alt="Eindwerk + gevoegd"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto5.png" alt="Begin van een tweede werk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto6.png" alt="Progressie van tweede werl"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto7.png" alt="Nog niet gevoegd eindwerk 2"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto8.png" alt="Eindwerk van een tweede werk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto9.jpg" alt="Begin van een derde werk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto10.jpg" alt="Progressie van eend erde werk"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto11.jpg" alt="Derde eindwerk nog niet gevoegd"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto12.jpg" alt="Derde eindwerk + gevoegd"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto13.jpg" alt="Houten vloer gelegd"> 
    <img class="Realisaties" src="fotos/Slide/Foto14.png" alt="Andere houten vloer gelegd"> 
</div>
<button class="controls" id="pause">Pause</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
var playing = true;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
var myIndex = 0;

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Realisaties");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {
        myIndex = 1
    }
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}


function pauseSlideshow(){
    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
    playing = false;
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
}

function playSlideshow(){
    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    playing = true;
    slideInterval = setInterval(carousel, 2000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function(){
    if(playing){
        pauseSlideshow();
    }
    else{
        playSlideshow();
    }
};

carousel();
playSlideshow();
</script>
```

Comment: It finally works! :D
I really appreciate the help. Thanks a lot! :)